# What is the need to declare HttpServlet class as abstract?

Tags: servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why HttpServlet class is declared as abstract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742533/why-httpservlet-class-is-declared-as-abstract)

What is the need to declare HttpServlet class as abstract?What will be the problem if we can create an object of that class??

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, you'll find that the class is abstract, but none of the methods are.

So the only reason - is to enforce that we extend the class to use it's features.

It is based on design pattern called [Template Method](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/).